Get total value row last table jquery
I tried adding to the table by multiplying quantity by price, but the sum result doesn't appear. When one line of code is supposed to add up each row, this shows the total of all the rows in one line.
 <table class="table">                                              
    <thead>                                                 
        <tr>                                                        
        <th>Product Name</th>                                                       
        <th>QTY</th>                                                        
        <th>Box / Pcs</th>                                                      
        <th>Purchase Price </th>                                                        
        <th>Total Cost </th>                                                        
    </tr>                                               
    </thead>                                                
    <tbody>                                                 
        {% for v in product %}                                                      
        <tr>                                                            
            <td>
                <div class="productimgname">                                                                    
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="product-img stock-img">
                <img src="{{ base_url }}extends/assets/img/products/no_image.jpg" alt="product">
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ v.productName }}</a>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="product-quantity">
                    <span class="quantity-btn plus">+<i data-feather="plus-circle" class="plus-circle"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="quantity" class="quntity-input qty" name="qtyProduct" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idProduct" value="{{ v.productID }}">
                    <span class="quantity-btn minus"><i data-feather="minus-circle" class="feather-search"></i></span>  
                </div>                                                          
            </td>                                                           
            <td>                                                                
                <span class="pcs_box">0</span> Box / <span  class="pcs_total">0</span> pcs
            </td>                                                           
            <td>MYR. <span id="price" class="amount">{{ v.productPriceSellingMyr }}</span></td>                                                                                                                 
            <td>MYR. <span id="total" class="total_amount">0</span>                     
        <input type="hidden"  class="total_amount_" id="total_idr" name="total_idr" value="0" ></td>                                                        
        </tr>                                                   
        {% endfor %}                                                    
    </tbody>
</table>

This My Jquery
  
$().ready(function(){
    $(".minus").click(function(){
        changeQuantity(-1,this);
        calculate(this);
    });
    $(".plus").click(function(){
        changeQuantity(this);
        calculate(this);
    });
});

function calculate(obj){
    var price = parseFloat($(obj).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.amount').text()) || 0;
    var quantity = parseInt($(obj).parent().find('.qty').val());
    var total = price * quantity;    
    $(obj).parent().parent().parent().find('.total_amount').text(total).toLocaleString('en');
}


function changeQuantity(num,obj){
    $(obj).parent().find('.qty').val( parseInt($(obj).parent().find('.qty').val())+num);
}

When I run the total it only appears in one row of all the data, it should be the total for each row.

You are clicking the button, not the i, so .parent().parent().parent().parent() goes to tbody - use $(obj).closest("tr").find(".amount").val(... etc

Likely off topic: .text(total).toLocaleString('en') should be .text(total.toLocaleString('en'))

Likely off topic: each row has elements with id=, so the ID will be duplicated.  IDs must be unique.  Doesn't look like you're using them yet but will cause issues when you do

debug your values - eg debug price and you'll see that .text() gets the text of all matching elements combined, eg if you have 3 rows with amounts, 100,200,300, you get 100200300.   So then debug your selectors (and navigation) ($(obj).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.amount').length == number of rows - so selector must be wrong.

Finally, you're not passing all the parameters to changeQuantity so + never increases.  Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/jtm21ch7/

hai @fdomn-m thanks for support just only one remove .parent() and total with line one last row

It's generally better to use .closest() rather than a bunch of .parent() so you don't have to count, and don't have to change the code if you change the layout.
